PID for motor control
In the Texas Instrument document "InstaSPIN-FOC" explains in Chapter 11 how to do PID tuning for PMSMS and AC induction motors.
Specifically, in the speed loop, speedKp = (δ•speedKi) / K where:
δ = damping factor (you choose it arbitrarily)
K = 3/4•poles•flux (for PMSMS) .. or K = 3/4•poles•Id•(Lm)^2/Lr for AC induction motor
Texas Instrument uses for calculations its motors, that have very detailed datasheets with all the parameters described above.
I have some doubts:
1) Based on what do I choose the BW? It is not clear to me on a general level, the larger the better? It depends on the application I guess .. ie? E' espressa in Hz o rad/s nelle formule del PID?
2) In the case of PMSM, how much is the flux? ..flux means Ke constant of the motor and it's needed in the formula at the top to calculate speedKp. It is not in the datasheet of my engine.
I have tried estimating parameters with TI software, and among the estimated parameters there are: USER_MOTOR1_RATED_FLUX_VpHz and USER_MOTOR1_FLUX_EXC_FREQ_Hz.. maybe one of these two is Ke?

For high-dynamic applications like robotics or electric vehicles that require quick speed changes, a higher BW is preferred.
A lower BW suffices to avoid excessive noise or instability for steady-state applications like pumps or fans.
